# CELERY_ROUTES seems to be ignored

Tags: python-2.7, celery, django-celery

I'm using django and djcelery. Since some tasks are a bit heavy I want them in a separate queue.

According to the part about automatic routing in the [user guide](http://celery.github.com/celery/userguide/routing.html), you can achieve this through the settings variable `CELERY_ROUTES`. However this doesn't work, all tasks end up on the default queue. When I explicitly set the queue variable in my task class it DOES work.

In my settings file I have

```
CELERY_ROUTES = {"analysis.tasks.analyze_item": {"queue": "analysis_queue"}}
```

I start the celery worker with

python manage.py celeryd -Q analysis_queue

My task.py

```
class Analyze(Task):
    queue = 'analysis_queue' # <--- without this it doesn't work..
....


analyze_item = registry.tasks[Analyze.name]
```

Comment: Does your queue require a routing key? Also, are sure you don't have any relative naming issues?

Comment: I don't know about the routing key, as far as I know it's not required. It seems more likely to be a naming issue, I don't know what though. If I try this on the shell it works: 'from analysis.tasks import analyze_item' so to me it seems the path is correct.